# About words with a medial /d/ and a flapped /t/

Tags: grammar

Are words with a medial /d/ and a flapped /t/ considered homophones in American English?

Ex.
beading/beating
cording/courting
heeding/heating
padding/patting
riding/writing
seeding/seating
siding/(citing/siting)
wedding/wetting
medal/metal
ladder/latter
madder/matter
tidal/title
Adam/atom
bidder/bitter
leader/liter

Comment: As a native AmE speaker, we don’t consider them homophones because they don’t sound alike when spoken slowly. But the difference *does* shrink as I speed up.

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not. The vowel is longer before a /d/ than before a /t/, and this serves to help distinguish them. This is because in English, vowels lengthen before voiced consonants.

If the vowel is /aɪ/, in many American dialects the vowel not only lengthens but its quality also changes  (this is called [Canadian raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising)) and the words are quite distinguishable.

In the case of really short vowels, like *bitter* and *bidder* and *putting* and *pudding*, the length of the vowel doesn't help all that much to distinguish the words, but they're still generally not considered homophones.